I steered the bus towards the hard shoulder and finally got it to stop
A woman is telling about how she managed to stop a bus on a motorway after the driver collapsed while driving. She says:
I steered the bus towards the hard shoulder and finally got it to stop. BBC - The woman who stopped a bus after the driver collapsed (see:00:50-00:55)
As far as I know, "get someone to do something" is used when you arrange someone to do something, but in this case, she doesn't arrange someone to stop the bus, and actually she does it herself.
So, I wonder why she said "....and finally got it to stop" rather than "....and finally stopped it." Are both ok, or would it have been wrong if she had said "....finally stopped it"?

But from "got it to stop" it is obviously not someone but something: get something to do something.

Yes, that is right, I noticed that before writing, but I simply wanted to put the structure of causative, which we were taught at school. Anyway, I understand your point, so can we say "got it to stop" in this sentence means that "I managed to stop the bus."?

Yes, but also see the answers of professionals below for the most common way of wording.

Get someone to do something can also mean to persuade or induce them to do it. "I finally got him to sit down."

Even though a bus is inanimate, there's an element of persuading it or inducing it to stop here, bringing it under control and imposing your will, hence "got it to stop". Whereas if you just shot the tires or drove it into a brick wall, "I stopped the bus" would be more appropriate.

There are two different idioms here:

Get {somebody] to do something

means to ask, command, persuade, bully, wheedle, or otherwise cause the person to do the thing.

Get [somebody or something] to do something

means to bring about the thing happening, usually with an implication of overcoming a difficulty or challenge.
Sometimes they overlap, and there can be ambiguity.

Really? You think these are two different usages? Or do they both mean "cause [the object] [to do something]"? And perhaps it's a mild case of anthropomorphisation, e.g. "I finally persuaded the old engine to turn over," but does that really mean they're separate?

I think they are, @AndyBonner, though there is an overlap. The first one, where the subject of the dependent clause is human-ish, does not necessarily imply any difficulty or challenge, but the second, where it is not, does.

I got something to do something is synonymous with "I managed to get something to do something"; that is, "I managed to make it do what I wanted it to do".
It is used primarily in contexts where the thing is not at first doing what you want it to do, and you must take some out-of-the ordinary measure or measures in order to achieve your purpose.

The door was stuck but I got it to open by giving it a kick.
The automatic transmission was making a terrible grinding sound but I got the car to move by putting it in second gear and managed to make it all the way home.

There can also be an adjectival complement:

I got the door open by giving it a kick.

The meaning is the same as with the infinitival complement.
Since there's a basic adjective already in existence, to say "got it opened" using the adjective formed from the past participle sounds a bit strange to my ear, though when there is no such adjective the participial adjective sounds fine:

I got the children to settle. They're doing some finger painting.
I got the children settled. They're doing some finger painting.
.


Good explanation. Thanks, based on your example, it might have very close versions in meaning. So can you also clarify what difference would there be if I said "The door was stuck but I got it opened" VS "......but I got it open." VS ".... but I got it to open".

@Yunus Beware of asking new questions in comment sections; if there's a separate question worth asking, open it separately. Meanwhile, what would make you think there's any difference in meaning between these three?

@AndyBonner, OK I understand your point. You are right. The reason I ask is that I see all of these variations being used, with almost the same meaning, however I can't be sure if they are really the same in meaning, because I am a non-native speaker.

I'll add a P.S. addressing "got it open" and "got it opened".


I steered the bus towards the hard shoulder and finally got it to stop.


I steered the bus towards the hard shoulder and finally  stopped it.

The OP's proposed version is fine.  The original version should also be understood.  We could also consider this idiom with similar meaning: bring something to a stop.
I ... finally brought the bus to a stop.
This use has lots of hits in Google Books; got the bus to stop has just about two pages of hits.
M+W defines bring something to a stop:

to bring (something) to a state in which it is no longer moving
He slowly brought the car to a stop.

brought the bus to a stop
got the bus to stop
